# Cant find mistake that causes IllegalThreadStateException

Tags: java, sockets

Whenever I try to reconnect to my socket pressing the connect button AGAIN after I disconnected with my dc button it always causes an IllegalThreadStateException. I have a Method for connecting to the socket and writing some messages to it and a Thread for reading messages I get from the socket. I cant find the problem because in my opinion it should all work how I want it to work.

My Connect Method:

```
public void Connect() throws IOException{

    this.BotName = jTextField1.getText();
    this.AuthKey = jTextField2.getText();
    this.Channelname = jTextField3.getText();

    this.jTextArea1.append("Starting Connection To: " + Server + "\n");

        try{    

        socket = new Socket(Server, Port);

        connected = socket.isConnected() && !socket.isClosed();

        out = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        isr = socket.getInputStream();
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr));

        if (!this.ReadServerMessages.isAlive()){            
             ReadServerMessages.start();          
        }

        out.write("PASS " + this.AuthKey + "\r\n");
        out.write("NICK " + this.BotName + "\r\n");
        out.write("USER " + this.BotName + " 8 " + this.BotName + "\r\n");
        out.write("CAP REQ :twitch.tv/membership \r\n");
        out.write("CAP REQ :twitch.tv/commands \r\n");
        out.write("CAP REQ :twitch.tv/tags \r\n");
        out.write("JOIN #" + this.Channelname + "\r\n");
        out.flush();

        if(connected = true){

            this.jButton1.setEnabled(false);
            this.jTextArea1.append("Successfully Connected!\n");
            this.jButton3.setEnabled(true);
            this.jLabel15.setText("YES");
            this.jLabel15.setForeground(Color.green);

        }

        }catch(Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();

        }     

    }
```

My ReadMessages Thread:

```
Thread ReadServerMessages = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {

        try {

            while((ServerMsg != null) && (connected = true)){

            ServerMsg = in.readLine();

            jTextArea3.append(ServerMsg + "\n");

            PingCheck();
            getViewerMsg();

            CheckCommand();

            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException exe) {
            exe.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

});
```

The full exception I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:705)
at main.TwitchBotFenster.Connect(TwitchBotFenster.java:98)
at main.TwitchBotFenster.jButton1ActionPerformed(TwitchBotFenster.java:1420)
at main.TwitchBotFenster.access$100(TwitchBotFenster.java:25)
at main.TwitchBotFenster$2.actionPerformed(TwitchBotFenster.java:599)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: You can't restart a thread. `if(connected = true)` should most probably be `if(connected)`, and you should learnt he Java naming conventions and stick to them. Variables and methods start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Thanks for the advice :)! I'm not trying to restart it. It should just keep reading incoming messages. This is why I thought that I should use `if (!this.ReadServerMessages.isAlive())` because it would only be executed once. But I'm still getting this exception. @JBNizet

Comment: We don't have enough of the code to explain But you wouldn't get this exception is you called start() on the thread for the first time. So you are trying to restart it.

Comment: @JBNizet The first time I press my connect button everything works fine. But when I disconnect (I'm not doing anything with the Thread, it keeps running) and then press connect AGAIN, it gives me this exception. The `isAlive()` method tells me if the Thread is running right? In this case, it IS running so the thread should not be started again. But it doesn't work. Am I thinking wrong?

Comment: Again, the code is not sufficient to explain. But if you disconnect, I assume you close the socket. And it you close the socket, then its InputStream is closed. So readLine() will throw an IOException, and your thread will thus stop running. But again; trust the stack trace: it tells you that you're claling start() on the thread. So you are.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you very much. Yes, I was closing the socket when disconnecting and that probably caused an exception on my thread. The thread was probably marked as "not alive" (dont know if I can call it dead) but it was somehow still alive(?) so it could not really start the thread again because it was somehow still running. At least I know where the problem is now. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

There is only one error that causes this exception: trying to start a thread that has already finished.

NB:

```
connected = socket.isConnected() && !socket.isClosed();
```

`isConnected()` is true and `isClosed()` is false at the point you are evaulating this statement. It is pointless. And neither of these methods can be used to tell you anything about the state of the *connection* at any later stage. They are there to tell you the state of *your `Socket`*.

```
if (connected = true)
```

This is an assignment, not a comparison. It should be `if (connected)`, but see above.